# Apply security in grpc client server node js

Tags: grpc, grpc-node

I am new to GRPC call, i created 1 server and client,now how to restrict other clients to connect my server

i haven't tried any solution,because not know the best solution and i have limited time to appy solution so posting  question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a server with secure credentials as mentioned [here](https://grpc.io/docs/guides/auth/#nodejs)

there are different methods there, you can choose any of it

I prefer SSL method

to create a connection with ssl_creds

```
const root_cert = fs.readFileSync('path/to/root-cert');
const ssl_creds = grpc.credentials.createSsl(root_cert);
const stub = new helloworld.Greeter('myservice.example.com', ssl_creds);
```

for generating SSL I have used [git repo](https://github.com/gbahamondezc/node-grpc-ssl) and follow the instruction according to README

Comment: I tried it, thanks